# Graph API Access denied error

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have been using the Graph API’s calendar endpoints for reading the current calendar events of all conference rooms at our organization (as needed in our application).

Our AAD application had the required permissions setup for cert based delegated access.

AAD permissioning setup
[image: AAD permissioning setup]

We were able to read the events but starting last Friday, we noticed that all our calls are failing with the access denied error message when we try to hit the endpoint.

Delegated permissions setup
[image: Delegated permissions setup]

Sample Errors:

```
"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ErrorAccessDenied\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.\",\r\n    \"innerError\": {\r\n      \"request-id\": \"4e86b67f-c790-4622-8c52-5560ada18809\",\r\n      \"date\": \"2017-12-20T00:59:42\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ErrorAccessDenied\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.\",\r\n    \"innerError\": {\r\n      \"request-id\": \"43986eec-2b2a-4e0c-b2e6-d5cacfd9e583\",\r\n      \"date\": \"2017-12-20T01:15:04\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

Additional info:
Token payload data:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/",
  "iat": 1513731142,
  "nbf": 1513731142,
  "exp": 1513735042,
  "aio": "<removed>",
  "app_displayname": "<removed>",
  "appid": "17e23349-efa0-4b31-b04f-c8e16754bcb8",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "e_exp": 262800,
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/",
  "oid": "028bc190-3171-4699-90ad-65a0b6cc9d21",
  "sub": "028bc190-3171-4699-90ad-65a0b6cc9d21",
  "tid": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
  "uti": "nTP0r5PyPUqQoNS3WmUKAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

I did notice the token payload is missing any scope but given that it was working earlier and no known changes were made to our AAD instance, I doubt whether that is the real issue but let me know if I am missing something there.

I tried switching the AAD application to another one which also has the admin consented permissions setup but that resulted in the same error as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no scopes/roles in the token, the problem is probably that the permissions have not been granted.

You can grant the permissions in your tenant by clicking the Grant permissions button there.

You can also find some information about how grants work and how you can debug this kind of problems in my blog: https://joonasw.net/view/the-grant-requires-admin-permission

Comment: There was an issue at the tenant level which caused the admin grants on the permissions to be removed and they had failed to add it back. Contacting the AAD support team and having them add back the admin grants fixed it for us